# What is the name of the bond between phosphate and the sugar in a nucleotide?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, terminology, nucleic-acids

I am slightly confused about what the name of the bond is between the phosphate and sugar within a nucleotide. All my research comes up with is a phosphodiester bond being the backbone of DNA. But within a single nucleotide, would we perhaps call it a phosphoester bond (all of my searches of phosphoester bond correct it to phosphodiester, so I don't think the term 'phosphoester' is in use...); or maybe it would be an O-glycosidic bond as it is a sugar molecule covalently bonded to another molecule via an O atom?

Comment: Please do not ask multiple questions.

Comment: @another 'Homo sapien' Glycosidic bonds certainly do not always involve an O atom (heard of N,C and S glycosidic bonds? Now THAT is something you can find out on Wikipedia). And I do not get your point- even if a glycosidic bond required an O atom, there is one between the sugar and the phosphate group.

Comment: @another'Homosapien' see above comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Phosophoester](https://www.reference.com/science/phosphoester-bond-81a17ce9208f9ff7) is a valid term. There are at least a [1000 peer-reviewed articles](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22phosphoester%22) that use this term. [IUPAC Goldbook](https://goldbook.iupac.org/N04255.html) defines nucleotides as:

> Compounds formally obtained by esterification of the 3 or 5 hydroxy group of nucleosides with phosphoric acid. They are the monomers of nucleic acids and are formed from them by hydrolytic cleavage."

Phosphoester or phosphoric ester means an ester of phosphoric acid.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on WIYSIWG's correct answer:

Each nucleotide *contains* one phosphoester bond (between a phosphate O and sugar 5'-C). Additionally, two nucleotides are *connected* by one phosphoester bond (between a phosphate O and sugar 3'-C). So in a polymer of multiple nucleotides (DNA, RNA), the repeating monomer unit contains two phosphoester bonds, on "top" (5') and "below" (3') the sugar. Since the repeating unit contains two phosphoester bonds, and the phosphates alternate with the sugars in the sequence, we call this a sugar-phosphate backbone held together by phospho*di*ester bonds/linkages.

Schematic of single nucelotide  featuring vertical line as phosphoester bond (to 5' C):

$P \\
| \\
[sugar]-[base]\\
\\$

Two nucleotides, each with an internal phosphoester bond and with a new phosphoester bond connecting them (spanning 5' of one sugar to 3' of the next):

$P \\
| \\
[sugar]-[base]\\
|\\
P\\
| \\
[sugar]-[base]\\
\\$

Repeating unit in nucleotide polymer, with alternating sugar-phosphate backbone and one *phosphodiester* bond/linkage per unit/nucleotide residue (the ... ellipses indicate pattern continues for the entire nucleic acid polymer, with hydroxyls capping the very ends):

$...\\
P\\
| \\
[sugar]-[base]\\
|\\
...\\$

Comment: phosphomonoester is also a common term for the first case