# What is exactly a phosphoester bond?

Tags: phosphorylation, phosphate

I've spent some hours trying to understand what exactly is a phosphoester bond, but I'm still confused and at this point I just want to throw myself out of the window. I've already read [that post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/54383/what-is-the-name-of-the-bond-between-phosphate-and-the-sugar-in-a-nucleotide) which treats the question but it doesn't really help me since, according to [the link given by WYSIWYG♦](https://www.reference.com/science/phosphoester-bond-81a17ce9208f9ff7):

> A phosphoester bond is a bond between the phosphorous atom of a phosphate group and an oxygen atom.

But considering the answer of electronpusher:

> Each nucleotide contains one phosphoester bond (between a phosphate O and sugar 5'-C).

It doesn't really make sense to me, since such a bond (in a nucleotide) is not exactly a bond between the phosphorous atom of the phosphate group and an oxygen atom (that is, it's a O-C bond, not a P-O bond).

So, what is exactly a phosphoester bond? Is it a O-glycosidic bond between the sugar (ribose or 2'-deoxyribose, in a nucleotide) and the phosphate group? Or is it the bond that there is between the phosphorous atom of a phosphate group and an oxygen atom of the same phosphate group?

I'm really confused and desperate by all this, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can find a diagram of the structure of a phospho **di**ester bond in any biochemistry text eg. [Lodish et al.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21514/#A803) and the definition: "A covalent bond in which two hydroxyl groups form ester linkages to the same phosphate group; joins adjacent nucleotides in DNA and RNA". So the question is do you know what an ester linkage is and do you know what a phosphate group is? If not you should try WIkipedia or a basic chemistry book. I shall vote to move to SE Chemistry but you should be able to answer this yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A phosphoester bond *is* in fact a bond between the phosphorus atom of a phosphate group and an oxygen atom. Your confusion comes from the fact that electronpusher's statement is inaccurate.

Instead, electronpusher should have said:

> Each nucleotide contains one phospho**di**ester bond **(between a phosphate O & a 5'-C on one sugar belonging to one nucleotide, and then another bond between a phosphate O & a 3'-C on another sugar belonging to another nucleotide)**.

More elegantly put, "*a phospho**di**ester bond occurs when **two** of the hydroxyl groups in phosphoric acid react with hydroxyl groups on other molecules to form **two** ester bonds*" ([source](https://chem.libretexts.org/LibreTexts/Sacramento_City_College/SCC%3A_Chem_309_-_General%2C_Organic_and_Biochemistry_(Bennett)/Chapters/13%3A_Functional_Group_Reactions/13.10%3A_Phosphoester_Formation)).

**The resulting bond is between O-C because the hydroxyl groups react with each other and [transesterification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transesterification) occurs**. The OH from the phosphate *interacts* with the OH (attached to the carbon) from the sugar, transesterification occurs, thus leaving only 1 oxygen, of which is the oxygen in the P-**O**-C bond sequence, exhibited in the following image.

[image: Phosphodiester bonds between three nucleotides]

The next image is a simplification of the reaction mechanism. Dehydration does not actually occur (transesterification does, as mentioned), but instead, this image is provided as to more easily identify which entities are involved in the reaction, as to more directly address the concerns expressed by the OP. The true reaction mechanism can be found [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/61319/is-water-released-when-a-phosphodiester-bond-is-made-between-two-nucleotides-dur/61352#61352).

[image: Phosphoester bond reaction mechanism]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! However, I still don't see why the bonds we are talking about are phosphoester (or phosphodiester) bonds, since they are both O-C bonds and not O-P bonds... :/

Comment: @AlissaDeschamps The *resulting* bond is between O-C because the hydroxyl groups **react** with each other (as can be read in the provided definition) and dehydration occurs (water is produced). The OH from the phosphate interacts with the OH from the sugar carbon, which produces H2O, leaving only 1 oxygen, of which is the oxygen in the P-O-C bond sequence, exhibited in the provided image.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for the clarification. Does that mean that the phosphoester bonds that everyone is talking about when they think of nucleotides are actually the bonds between the phosphorous atom and the oxygen one? And the O-C bonds would be glycosidic bonds?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edit and the help, you're awesome! :)

Comment: You're quite welcome! Study smart, not hard ;)

Comment: Good answer, I would just say that  the condensation reaction shown is thermodynamically unfavourable. In realty, nucleotides are joined together by transesterfication. See this question and answers: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/61319/is-water-released-when-a-phosphodiester-bond-is-made-between-two-nucleotides-dur/61352#61352

Comment: @canadianer Thanks for that. I've updated my answer to include and reference this.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and edits ; do you know if transesterification occurs only for the linkage of the phosphate group with the 3'C of the sugar or if it occurs as well with the 5'C? (I'm asking this because my book, "Molecular biology of the gene" by Watson and al., says that dehydration occurs without saying there could be a difference between the 3'C and 5'C...)

Comment: @Charles - Nice job, and great attitude. I never heard of a phosphoester bond (only *di*ester) until just now.